# log1p function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, precision, floating-accuracy, logarithm

Can anyone please help clarifying  what is the meaning of the following sentence in [log1p](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/log1p.html) reference page.

> y = log1p(x) computes log(1+x), compensating for the roundoff in 1+x.

I look at the [source code](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/imurray2/code/matlab_octave_missing/log1p.m) and I do not understand how rewriting a function as follows helps:

```
p1 = xs + 1;
careful = xs.*log(p1)./(p1-1);
```

Does it mean in MATLAB the round-off error of (xs+1) is worse than the log function when a xs is small?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First, the round-off error of `(xs + 1)` for small `xs` is not a MATLAB-specific problem, but a natural result of how a double precision number is represented in most popular computer languages. [IEEE 754 double number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) allows only ~16 significant decimal digits. When you add two numbers that are separated by more than 16 orders of magnitude, say `1` and `1e-32`, the result `1.000...[32x]...0001` cannot all fit into a double number, and the `1e-32` part will be effectively truncated, so you will get `1 + 1e-32 == 1`. That's where the rounding error comes from.

In your code snippet, when `xs` is small enough, `p1` will `=1`, then `careful` will become `NaN`. When this happens, you know `xs` is too small to be used in  the regular calculation process, so we might as well just return `xs` instead. However, note that this is not the official source of `log1p` in MATLAB, but rather it is someone else's empirical solution intended to mimic the behavior of `log1p`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understood if xs is less than or equal to 10^-16 then 1+10^-16 will be considered as 1 under IEEE 754 double number. But from what I understood this implementation (log1p)is mainly designed for the cases that  xs is small but 1+xs != xs .(theorem 4 [1]). I cannot follow how this helps decreasing error in such cases(xs is small but 1+xs != xs ). [1]https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html